# Forcing Android To Update

Tags: updates, android-versions

I have a Samsung J7 smartphone. It's currently running version 8.1 and I want to improve it to Android version 10. By clicking "update" in settings, it says "the latest version has already been installed". What would be the risks associated with installing manual updates?

Comment: If it says it has the latest version then no updates are possible, manual or otherwise. BTW Samsung hasn't upgraded that to 10. If you want to upgrade to 10,then you need to root and flash a custom ROM for which XDA is the best place to search

Comment: Can I restore My current update after version 10, If I wanted?

Comment: You can check on XDA but No in most cases